# Freeze during intensive calculations in multi-threading C++ program (boost)

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I wrote a c++ program using boost.
My program is like :

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
boost::thread workerThread(worker)
// Waiting end of calculation...
workerThread.join();
return 0; 
}

void worker()
{
// Ultra intensive calculation here. Big loop on big vectors, ...
}
```

On some "little" calculs, it's ok, the program returns the good result.
But if i increase the inputs, the program starts to freeze the computer. (he returns the good result though).
I thought that using multi-threading can resolve this, but apparently not..

What do you think ? Is there a possibility to reduce the memory used by the worker thread, to allow the user to continue to use his computer ?
I tried to find some bugs in my calcul code, but didnt find one now.

Comment: Adding a thread does not unfreeze the computer. Not sure why you are thinking that. If you elaborate I'll explain why it is not the case.

Comment: Why do you expect your program to *not* use the CPU time it can get? Did you code anything that says "ok, I'd better do nothing for a little bit"? If not, then your program will work with all the CPU time it is given.

Comment: If your worker uses a loop / repeated operation, add a temporizing instruction (sleep(5ms)) to be te4xecuted every time - it could be that the intensive calculations are implemented in a way that is not optimized for context switching by your compiler (such as deep recursive calls). That would mean there is no context switching while the worker runs and your system freezes.

Answer (score 2):

`join()` will block until the work from the thread has been finished, your program can't naturally return before that if the code you've shown correctly depicts your scenario.

You're not really doing anything in parallel - you simply launch an extra thread that does the entire thing and then you wait for the thread to finish.

As I mentioned in the comments, it's extremely unlikely you're slowing down your system by using your CPU a lot. I think you're just gobbling up too much memory and OS is busy paging - but unless you elaborate, I can't help any further.

Comment: Oh yeah that's true. In fact i will parallelize my code later. I just want to not freeze my computer when my program is running. Do you know a way to ? Maybe a way to limits CPU usage ?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, OS should assign time slices fairly, maybe you're munching up memory and you'll end up thrashing with paging rather than really keeping your CPU busy.